# I want to compare two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Assume that I have two arrays as follow:

```
$array1 = array(1, 3, 5);
$array2 = array('x'=> 1, 'y'=> 2, 'z'=> 5);
```

How to check that the two arrays are exactly the same in most efficient and proper way and it doesn't care the keynames of the ***$array2**.

*I want to make a function which should return true if values are exactly the same, and false if any of the ones are different both in value(s) and number of elements.*

Thanks for your time and reading.

Comment: if you want to check for values, use `array_values` function for second array and then check for equality

Comment: regarding *exactly the same*, what about the order of the elements?

Comment: Then, tbh, I'd suggest to simply (after comparing the length) traverse one array and test for strict equality (`===`) of both elements. This way you can return false on the first none-equal element.

Comment: @Uday Sawant & Yoshi yes, that's right, check the order ot the elements as well.

Comment: @Thavarith then equality check would be a good choice, additionally as suggested by @Yoshi you can use strict equality (`===`) to check data types of elements eg. `1 === '1'`.

Comment: @Uday Sawant, yes, it works well with the array values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 array_values($array1) === array_values($array2)
```

Assuming that arrays have same order.

Comment: Converting the result of `array_values()` to string, no matter what the array content, will always result in the literal string `Array`, so this will always be true.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks mate, tottaly missed this

Comment: Actually, your code works well array_values does convert values to string unless using equality check.

Answer (score 4):

In the simplest case you can just use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff). It ignores the keys in your second array, but also the order of the values. It would return an empty set if the arrays are equal:

```
 if (count(array_diff($array1, $array2)) == 0) {
    // equal
```

You could also compare the arrays directly, after stripping keys from the second:

```
 if ($array1 == array_values($array2)) {
```

That would additionally compare the order of contained values.

Comment: I think that the second example would probably be best to pass both arrays through `array_values()`, since in this situation one may not know that the keys of `$array1` are contiguous without looping to check, and `array_values()` will correct this. Also you could safely check the result of `array_diff()` as a boolean in this example, `if (!array_diff($array1, $array2)) { //equal` is fairly safe and does not have the overhead of a call to `count()`.

Comment: Thanks @mario, I think the second using array_values work well.

Comment: It works well provided that we convert both arrays using array_values and comparing ===

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$array1 = array(1, 3, 5);
$array2 = array('x'=> 1, 'y'=> 2, 'z'=> 5);
$array2 = array_values($array2);
echo $array1 == $array2 ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: It works well provided that we convert both arrays using array_values and comparing ===

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<?php    
$array1 = array ("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "red");    
$array2 = array ("a" => "green", "yellow", "red");    
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);    
if(count($result) == 0)
{
  .......  
}    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Code Monkey, in this case, what if the second arrays: $array2 contains sames values as $array1 and $array2 also has extra element? array_diff will return 0...so if-condition becomes true...which is not

Answer (score 0):

array_diff will do the job for you:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
if(empty($result)){
    // arrays contain the same values!
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Bain, in this case, what if the second arrays: $array2 contains sames values as $array1 and $array2 also has extra element? array_diff will return 0...so if-condition becomes true...which is not

Comment: array_diff returns an array containing the elements which are not in both arrays. If an element is in array2 but not array1, array_diff will return an array containing the element. In this case, empty($result) will be equal to false and therefore the check holds true. - http://php.net/array_diff

Comment: Nope, array_diff returns result of different of $array1 not $array2. i did check it.

Comment: Yes, and what does the function empty do!?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class containing an array and make that class implement the Comparable interface, for example http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.interfaces.php#69467